# How to return two one to many relationships in an API response with Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, I have three models - Events, Groups and Individuals. I'm trying to create an API response that provides a list of groups AND the individuals in each group. I've been able to create a response that provides a list of the groups, but I'm not sure how to also PROPERLY include the individuals of each group.

I thought about just looping through each from the first response and making another query for each, but that seemed like overkill. So, the question is how can I include the Individuals for each Group within the response as well.

I have all three eloquent models defined as such:

**Events:**

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}
```

**Groups:**

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
}
public function individuals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Individual');
}
```

**Individuals:**

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

Then I have my route:

```
Route::get('/events/{id}/groups', 'EventsController@groups');
```

Then that controller has the function to return the list of groups:

```
public function groups($eventId)
{
    $event= Event::find($eventId);
    $groups= $event->groups()->paginate();

    return $groups;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. To clarify, I'd be looking for a response that looks something like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    group_name: 'Group Name',
    individuals: [ .. array of individuals .. ]
}
```

Or if someone could give feedback on a better or more standard way to do it, I'd be open to that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) with the `with()` method:

```
public function groups($eventId)
{
    $event= Event::find($eventId);
    $groups= $event->groups()->with('individuals')->paginate();

    return $groups;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something way simpler than I was thinking...thank you. I will accept answer when I can!

Comment: Don't hesitate to dive into the Eloquent documentation, it is full of great tips I never saw on posts/articles before :)

Comment: You could actually do this: `$event = Event::with('groups.individuals')->find($eventId)` and then return like this: `return $event->groups`. It's not going to execute any less queries, just makes for nicer code I think

Comment: @devk your code so El_Matella's will create 3 queries. OP doesn't need Event, he wants to return 'a list of groups and the individuals in each group'.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It will execute same queries and return the groups (check the return statement, I'm returning ->groups not the event).

Comment: That being said, you could do it with 1 less query actually, since you get the $eventId as route parameter, you don't need to query for the event. You could simply do this:  `return Group::where('event_id', $eventId)->with('individuals')->paginate()`.

Comment: I actually agree with @Alexey Mezenin, his code is **better** because it saves a request. (However, the question was not about saving MySQL time execution, but on eager loading relationships)

Comment: To be fair, I personally prefer to use Model Binding, that makes an additional request also. I make this sacrifice for the beauty of the code. But I am probably wrong on this one

Comment: @El_Matella I agree that my comment didn't answer his question any better than yours did, that's why I didn't post it as answer :) What I don't understand is why would either one of these codes save a request? There should be exactly one request no matter the number of lines of code/queries.

Comment: Your answer is also good and don't trigger any other request, it was my response and Tom's code that triggered one, I think we all agree haha

Answer (score 3):

Since you already know event ID, you can use `Group` model directly and load individuals by using [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method. This code will create just two queries and it's less verbose:

```
public function groups($eventId)
{
    return Group::where('event_id', $eventId)->with('individuals')->paginate(5);
}
```